# Can't get server running in Rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.8.7, ruby-enterprise-edition

I've inherited a pretty old Rails app (running **v2.3.18** on **Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7**) and I'm trying to get it up and running locally.

After installing the gems and performing migrations I'm trying to startup the server with `rails server` as I'm used to, but unfortunately it doesn't start the server but instead generates duplicates the current directory to a `/server` directory.

It looks like this:

```
➜  my_app $ rails server
      create
      create  app/controllers
      create  app/helpers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts
      create  config/environments
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/locales
      ... etc ...
```

In fact, anything I run after `rails` just duplicates the code to a new directory with that name. So `rails blah` would duplicate the entire project to `/blah`.

I've never encountered this before in newer versions of Ruby/Rails. I'd appreciate any help in fixing this!

If it makes a difference, I'm using **rbenv** to manage my Ruby version.

Comment: Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526424/how-to-start-rails-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `ruby ./script/server` or `./script/server start` instead of `rails server`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526664/2113461